# Windows 8: Single User logon only, all others get black screen

Tags: windows-8

I have an issue that I caused months ago, but do not remember how I caused it so that I can now undo it.

The initial request was to lock down the Windows 8 computer to a single user. I locked it down to 2 users (but I do not recall HOW I locked it down) on the domain. All other users were not supposed to be able to log in.

Now, they want to undo what I did. But my documentation doesn't include HOW I did it. I can log into the system as the main administrator on the domain. Other admin accounts though do not work. Duplicating the admin account does not work.

Whenever anyone other than the main system administrator (domain\administrator) logs in, I get a solid black screen with mouse.

I need help undoing whatever I did. I 'believe' I did it in the Group Policy of that machine, but I don't recall how. Please help!!

Comment: Are you able to hold Ctrl Alt Delete start task manager in open a new tasks such as Explorer. Exe

Comment: CTRL ALT DELETE gave no response.

Answer (score 0):

If it is caused by local Group Policy, there are a couple ways to reset those policies:

#### Local Group Policy Editor (recommended)

Run `gpedit.msc`. Open *Computer Configuration*, then *Administrative Templates*. Sort by State (just click the header) so you can see all changed settings. Change any unwanted settings to *Not configured*. Do the same for *User Configuration*. It's also worth checking for scripts (e.g. logon script, startup script); these can be found in *Scripts* under *Windows Settings*.

#### Blowing away the local policy store

(In case the above doesn't help.) Navigate to `\Windows\System32` either with Explorer or with an elevated command prompt. Clear out (not delete) the `GroupPolicy` and `GroupPolicyUsers` folders. **Danger!** I haven't personally tested this, but I have heard that it does the job. It's always a good plan to make a backup before torching something.

### Domain policy

If it's not a local Group Policy issue, there might be something in the normal Group Policy that's causing it. I recommend running [Resultant Set of Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781830(v=ws.10).aspx) to see what policy settings are in effect.

### Other programs/scripts

Finally, there might be programs set up to run automatically and cause such shenanigans. To look at and remove such things, I recommend Sysinternals [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). It provides a list of things that start automatically, with checkboxes to disable them. It can even analyze an offline system and user profile.

Comment: It was caused by local Group Policy. I went into the local user users, and under groups, the 'user' I had removed 'domain users', NT Authority\Authenticated Users, and NT Authority\Interactive. In their place I had put the individual users I wanted to allow. Once I realized what I had done I was able to go back in, remove the individual users, add in the 3 I had initially removed, and boom, working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by local Group Policy.

I had originally gone into the local user users, and under groups, the 'user' I had removed 'domain users', NT Authority\Authenticated Users, and NT Authority\Interactive. In their place I had put the individual users I wanted to allow.

Once I realized what I had done I was able to go back in, remove the individual users, add in the 3 I had initially removed, and boom, working correctly.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Interesting that it let them logon but just gave them black